# Show that martingale sequence converges to zero

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

I am dealing with a positively bounded martingale sequence generated by the process

$Y_t = \begin{cases}
         3Y_{t-1}/Y_0, \quad \ \text{with probability} \ \frac{1}{4} \\
         \frac{1}{3}Y_{t-1}/Y_0, \quad \text{with probability} \ \frac{3}{4} 
       \end{cases} \quad t \in \mathbb{N}$

for some deterministic $Y_0 > 0$. From simulation i guess that $Y_t \xrightarrow[]{n \rightarrow \infty}0$ but i cannot come up with a way to show this explicitly.

Comment: Any additional assumptions on $Y_0$? E.g. if $Y_0 = 1/6$, then $$Y_t = \begin{cases} 18 Y_{t-1}, & \text{w.p.} \frac{1}{4} \\ 2 Y_{t-1} & \text{w.p.} \frac{3}{4} \end{cases}$$ which means that $Y_t \to \infty$